# C++ writing an assign procedure for a container

Tags: c++, function, stl, iterator

I have a container, a class, and I would like to provide it with a method assign like STL do.

```
class myclass {
public:
   //...
   template < typename InputIterator >
   void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
   // ...
private:
   // ...
   std::vector<int> mystlcont;
   // ...
};

template < typename InputIterator >
myclass::assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
   this->mystlcont.clear();
   this->mystlcont.assign(first, last);
}
```

Ok. Well I compile, ok.
I use it now...

```
myclass m;
std::vector<int> vect;
vect.push_back(1);
vect.push_back(1);
vect.push_back(2);
vect.push_back(3);
vect.push_back(5);
vect.push_back(8);
vect.push_back(13);
m.assign(vect.begin(), vect.end()); // Line X
```

When calling function at line X, compiler returns a very very ugly error.

> workflow_test.hpp: In function ‘void
>   middleware::WorkflowSerializationTest()’:
>   workflow_test.hpp:114: error: invalid
>   cast from type
>   ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator
>
> > > ’ to type ‘middleware::TaskDescriptor*’
> > >       workflow_test.hpp:114: error: invalid
> > >       cast from type
> > >       ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator
> > >       ’ to type ‘middleware::TaskDescriptor*’

workflow_test is the file where I am calling the function assign, myclass repreents Workflow class in workflow.hpp and workflow.cpp... TaskDescriptor is the element in the vector (the type in the collection in myclass).

Do you know why this happens?

I suspect that there must be some operator to overload in my class to let this mechanism work correctly.... becaue it is not method implementation the problem, even if I write

```
template < typename InputIterator >
void myclass::assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
   // NOTHING WRITTEN IN THE BODY
}
```

When called raises the same exact "exception".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not your own container, but rather container wrapper.

But I see only one problem with your code: your `myclass::assign` definition does not have a return type specified.

This code actually works for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class MyWrapper {
    public:
        template <typename InputIterator>
        void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);

        const std::vector<int>& container() const { return container_m; }

    private:
        std::vector<int> container_m;
};

template <typename InputIterator>
void MyWrapper::assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    container_m.assign(first, last);
}

template <typename T>
void print(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << x << " ";
}

int main()
{
    MyWrapper mw;

    std::vector<int> vect;
    vect.push_back(1);
    vect.push_back(2);
    vect.push_back(3);
    vect.push_back(4);
    vect.push_back(5);
    vect.push_back(6);
    vect.push_back(7);

    mw.assign(vect.begin(), vect.end());

    std::for_each(mw.container().begin(), mw.container().end(), print<int>);
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: hmm  it works... I have to figure out what's wrong with my code. :) Thanks for your code.

Comment: OK, no it does not work on my class... I suspect that my class called myclass must implement some operator overloading... do you think so? and if it is right, do you know what operators it is necessary to implement?

Comment: As you can see, I do not overload any operator. And as I said in my post, only problem in your old code was, that did it not have a return type specified.